# Spring hibernate: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

**My DAO layer code is as follows:**

```
package com.app.dao;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.app.pojo.InterviewerPojo;

@Repository("interviewer_details_dao")
public class InterviewerDetailsDaoImpl implements InterviewerDetailsDao {

    @Resource(name="sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory factory;
    /*private HibernateTemplate template;
    public void setSessionFactory(){
        template = new HibernateTemplate(factory);
    }*/
    /*private HibernateTemplate template = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);*/
    @Override
    public void saveInterviewDetails(InterviewerPojo interviewerPojo) {

/*      Session sess = factory.getCurrentSession();
        try{
            sess.getTransaction().wasCommitted();
        Transaction trans = sess.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("a");
        sess.saveOrUpdate(interviewerPojo);
        sess.getTransaction().commit();}
        catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
        }*/
        System.out.println("b");
        factory.getCurrentSession().save(interviewerPojo);
    /*  System.out.println(interviewerPojo);
        template.saveOrUpdate(interviewerPojo);
        System.out.println("b");*/

        System.out.println("done");

    }

}
```

**the same code as above was running if i am getting the values from database as follows**
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select m from emp m).list;
**But as I writing another page to insert values then it is having problem**
**As you can see i used same concept, I populated MODEL(POJO) class by another MODEL(pojo) which i have taken from database by above query**
**and now debugging goes upto "template.saveOrUpdate" and throws exception as follows**

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'value for
>   hibernate_sequence' at line 1     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:100)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
>     at $Proxy24.executeQuery(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:112)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator$1.getNextValue(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:85)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.enhanced.OptimizerFactory$LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.generate(OptimizerFactory.java:350)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.generate(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:82)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:642)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:635)    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:631)     at
>   com.app.dao.InterviewerDetailsDaoImpl.saveInterviewDetails(InterviewerDetailsDaoImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   com.app.service.SaveInterviewerDetailsServiceImpl.saveDetails(SaveInterviewerDetailsServiceImpl.java:25)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>     at $Proxy19.saveDetails(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.app.controllers.EmployeePromoteController.validateDetails(EmployeePromoteController.java:67)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'value for
>   hibernate_sequence' at line 1     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2273)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
>     ... 61 more

---

POJO source code:

```
package com.app.pojo; 
import java.io.Serializable; 
import javax.persistence.*; 

@SuppressWarnings("serial") 
@Entity @Table(name="interviewer") 
public class InterviewerPojo implements Serializable {
    private int eid;

    private int vid; 

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) 
    private int i_eid; 

    private String i_name; 

    private String password; 

    public int getEid() { 
        return eid; 
    } 

    public void setEid(int eid) { 
        this.eid = eid; 
    } 
}
```

Hibernate config:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties"> 
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.formatsql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.showsql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
    </props> 
</property>
```

Comment: Show please InterviewerPojo source code

Comment: Also, easier to turn on SHOW SQL and gather incorrectly generated SQL from the log file.

Comment: @Taky : `<property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
       <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.formatsql">true</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.showsql">true</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
   </props>
    
  </property>`

but still it doesn't showing sql while table is generated automatically as application runs but i insert in interviewer via SAVE it gives exception :(

**I'll post InterviewerPojo in next comment**

Comment: @Taky :
**POJO is as follows:**
**Removed some getter/setters and toString()**
`package com.app.pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="interviewer")
public class InterviewerPojo implements Serializable{
 
 private int eid;
 private int vid;
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
 private int i_eid;
 private String i_name;
 private String password;
 public int getEid() {
  return eid;
 }
 public void setEid(int eid) {
  this.eid = eid;
 }
 
}`

Comment: Use edit question in future.

Comment: @Taky : **If i change hibernate.xml properties from "validate" to "create"or"update" then following error comes...
>**
`org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`

Comment: **Thank YOU very much for the help**
**But i find the solution, my POJO class have autogenerated e_id and i was assigning value to e_id ,that's why it was giving tons of exception**

Comment: Nevertheless configure your hibernate properly to achive better performance and suppress probable bugs with your syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In your error log, it showed that you're using MySQL. However, you configured Hibernate dialect was HSQLDialect.

> org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

You should remove this dialect property, Hibernate can automatically detect the right dialect through JDBC driver. Or you modify to the correct dialect on your own.